# Integrate Firebase with Titanium?

Tags: android, ios, titanium, firebase, titanium-mobile

i'm working on an app for android AND iOs with the titanium SDK. I want integrate firebase as a web service for the backend. I want to have users and save audio data on a cloud.

So my problem is how integrate Firebase API with titanium. I know there is a module for iOs, but it's only for iOs an me i want for android and iOS.
I'm looking for use the web view but no success...

So is it possible ? Or i've to use an other web service than Appcelerator cloud ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now there is no combine module available for both Android + iOS.

You need to use seperately in Appcelerator.

iOS : [iOS Module](http://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/11612?restoreSearch=true)

Android : [Android Module](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/9250?185602994&restoreSearch=true#!overview)

Comment: arf... Thanks man ! Maybe i'll swap for an other web service.

Comment: Both links are now broken

Comment: @YahyaUddin : May be Module for Android is removed but for iOS : [iOS](https://marketplace.axway.com/apps/11612#!overview)

Comment: Any links for Android